In unity I am making a game using photon pun and need some help withe the photon hash tables
so at the start of my game everyone gets a hash table made with this line
public ExitGames.Client.Photon.Hashtable playerProperties = new ExitGames.Client.Photon.Hashtable();
that happens in the lobby but then in the game i need to access it in another script and i don't know how to do that because it never access the key
i tried adding a player id i may work but where ever i go to look how to do it it is very confusing i have also changed to normal ints but was very buggy.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
